# Accessing OneDrive Folder on ElementaryOS

Tags: files, elementary-os, access-control

I have a computer with Windows 11 and Elementary OS 7. I can't access my OneDrive folder. I tried `fsutil reparsepoint delete "C:\Path\To\OneDrive\Folder"` but it output an access permission error, although I run it as an administrator `Error: Access to the cloud file is denied.`.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: run the command on windows